# Javascript function to allow only numbers dot and comma. I want to pass this input value by POST ajax call

Tags: javascript, html

The below code allows only number and dot.
How to improvise to allow the comma as well.

```
function isNumberandComma(evt) {
    var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: What regex call?

Comment: `evt.keyCode` is no longer recommended. [Use `evt.key` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

Comment: Regarding the input parameter, `evt` is an event, it is not a *simple* parameter (string, integer, etc.).  That function has to be executed when an event (I'd say `keyup` event) is triggered, like `window.addEventListener('keyup', isNumberandComma, false);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow it inside your condition:

```
function isNumberAndComma(evt) {
    const NUM_0 = 48;
    const NUM_9 = 57;
    const KEY_COMMA = 188;
    const KEY_DELETE = 46;
    const iKeyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    if (iKeyCode >= NUM_0 || iKeyCode <= NUM_9 || iKeyCode === KEY_COMMA || iKeyCode === KEY_DELETE)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `evt.keyCode` is no longer recommended. Please may you show an example using [`evt.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) as well.

Comment: when i use this code and enter the value as "12.345,78" the value gets stored as "12.345%2C78" which is not useful. Please help with the code which stores the value as it is.

Comment: @Arij, %2C would come from url-encoding the string; that's not happening in the ruction given here, but in your network call (presumably because you're unintentionally using GET instead of POST.)